# AJAX response returns html content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have an AJAX call in my codeigniter project. Here is my code:

in view :

```
$('#forgotPassword').click(function() {
        var base_url = '<?php echo base_url()?>'; 
        $('#forgotPasswordEmailError').text('');
        var email = $('#forgotPasswordEmail').val(); 
        console.log(email);
        if(email == ''){
            $('#forgotPasswordEmailError').text('Email is required');
        }else{
            $.ajax({
                url : base_url + 'Home/forgotPassword',
                type : 'POST',
                data : {email : email},
                success: function(data) {       
                    console.log(data);                  
                    //location.reload();
                }
            });
        }

    });
```

and controller :

```
public function forgotPassword() { 
   $email = $this->input->post('email');
   echo $email; 
}
```

but the response contains only the html content from my view. I couldn't identify what is happening.

Comment: What should the response be then?  i.e what's the expected result

Comment: Plase replace data : {email : email}, with  data : {'email' : email},

Comment: @ankitunde i just return the email id posted fron ajax request . but it displays whole html code in my view page

Comment: put a die after  echo $email; this will works like a charm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change your jquery code to

```
$('#forgotPassword').click(function() {
    var base_url = '<?php echo base_url()?>'; 
    $('#forgotPasswordEmailError').text('');
    var email = $('#forgotPasswordEmail').val(); 
    console.log(email);
    if(email == ''){
        $('#forgotPasswordEmailError').text('Email is required');
    }else{
        $.ajax({
            url : base_url + 'Home/forgotPassword',
            type : 'POST',
            data : {email : email},
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data) {       
                console.log(data);                  
                //location.reload();
            }
        });
    }

});
```

change your controller code like

```
public function forgotPassword() { 
   $email = $this->input->post('email');
   $response = ["email" => $email];
   echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Comment: Why use json though?? And not my upvote.. Also seems OP is just testing the response on Ajax call

Comment: because using json we can add more data to response easily in future @Akintunde

Comment: its working. thank you. but is it necessary to set dataType in ajax function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
echo $email;
```

use:

```
$response = ["email" => $email];

return json_encode($response);
```

And parse JSON, on client side, using `JSON.parse`.

Comment: you can send plain text over ajax, why use json?

Comment: @madalinivascu Plain text can be used, but using `JSON` gives more idea and in future, we can add more data to response.

Comment: i think it is not necessary to set dataType as json, because there is only one value. but anyways, its working now

Comment: @geeth I never said that dataType as json is required. However, sending a JSON response is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

hi maybe i can help someone, i had the same problem, in my case the error was here  "url : base_url + 'Home/forgotPassword'"

in this example i have to pass all way  like this  url : /anotherdirectory/Home/forgotPassword.php',
take a look in your "url"

$.ajax({
url : "change here fo works"',
type : 'POST',
data : {email : email},
dataType:'json',
success: function(data) {
console.log(data);
//location.reload();
}